# CSS Grid is not working in visual studio within the container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, containers, css-grid

CSS grid does not seem to be working, and I do not know why. Can anyone advise?

I have an index.html and css via Visual Studio. The html is basic. I made a container with a couple of items in.

This is the html

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </div>
  <div class="items">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </div>
  <div class="items">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit </div>
</div>
```

Can someone let me know as my take on it is the container is the parent so I use that class. I changed it to items and nothing.

I have tried changing the elements and that still did not work.
I don't have any other options.

Comment: What is your expected behavior?

Comment: In what way is it "not working"? Your posted code's running perfectly well in the snippet in your question.

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to understand what you are expecting. Please make your questions more specific in the future.

However, from what I understand, you are not too happy about the second element sitting at extreme right. Ok let's talk about that.

If you want to use the `grid-template-columns` property in your CSS, **Ask yourself these**:

1. How many columns do I want?
2. How much width do I want on each column?

**CASE 1:** If you want only **ONE** column, i.e. you want your list to look like this

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit
Lorem ipsum dolor sit
Lorem ipsum dolor, sit
```

**Use `grid-template-columns: auto`** *one auto for one column*

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </div>
  <div class="items">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </div>
  <div class="items">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit </div>
</div>
```

---

**CASE 2:** If you want **TWO** columns, i.e. you want your list to look like this

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit       Lorem ipsum dolor sit
Lorem ipsum dolor, sit
```

**Use `grid-template-columns: auto auto`** *two autos for two columns*

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </div>
  <div class="items">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </div>
  <div class="items">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit </div>
</div>
```

---

**CASE 3:** If you want **THREE** columns, i.e. you want your list to look like this

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit       Lorem ipsum dolor sit      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit
```

**Use `grid-template-columns: auto auto auto`** *three autos for three columns*

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </div>
  <div class="items">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </div>
  <div class="items">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit </div>
</div>
```

---

Now that you know how many columns you want, next you'd want to decide the width you want on each column **and width can be different for each column**.

If you don't want too much trouble, keep using `auto` to **automatically set the width for each column**. But if you're ready to do a little bit of tinkering, start changing the values.

For example, you can say `grid-template-columns: 1fr 200px 20%`, this will generate a grid of **three** columns.

- The first column will have width of 1fr.
- The second column will have width of 200px.
- The third column will have width of 20% of its parent, `container`.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 200px 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </div>
  <div class="items">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </div>
  <div class="items">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit </div>
</div>
```

---

So, in your case, `template-grid-columns: 1fr 200px` means the first column is of 1fr width and the second is of 200px. Use your browsers dev tools to verify it.

Here are some useful links:

1. [Play with grid-template-columns](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playdemo.php?filename=playcss_grid-template-columns)
2. [Learn more about Grid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8QSqwbSztnA)

I hope that solves your problem. Happy Coding!